# Alternative to using np.where with list to yield a series instead of an ndarray to be more amenable to converting into a dataframe?

Tags: python, list, pandas, comparison

Is there an alternative to use np.where with a list so that I can work with a series instead of an ndarray?

```
animal = ['Buffalo', 'Gazelle']

df.one = np.where(df.one.isin(animal),'Herding Animal', df.one)
```

Comment: Yes, the code is more or less the same, the only difference being the other question and solution is to check series against the list to create a new column to indicate if series is in the list. This question and solution's goal is replace the values in the existing column. In addition, jezrael provided alternate solutions in the comments, and one of those were picked. So, I guess that should be moved up to the solution. Or I can change the question. Yes, I will change the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one':['Buffalo','Gazelle','Leopard']})

print(df)
       one
0  Buffalo
1  Gazelle
2  Leopard

animal = ['Buffalo', 'Gazelle']
df.one.mask(df.one.isin(animal),'Herding Animal')
print (df)
              one
0  Herding Animal
1  Herding Animal
2         Leopard

df.to_frame()
```

Comment: @spacedustpi - It is possible, but better is use `df.one = df.one.mask(df.one.isin(animal),'Herding Animal')` with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html)

Comment: But if need replace - `df.one = df.one.replace(dict.fromkeys(animal, 'Herding Animal'))`

Comment: Love the dict.fromkeys method, so clever. I timed these techniques 100K times each with datetime library in microseconds(ms): mask: 519 ms, np.where: 147 ms, and dict.fromkeys: 1038 ms. So mask wins on account of time and its ease of use with dataframes - you were right.